# Kendo Datasource / Grid - Expecting a Itemchange event but only receive sync event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where the is a Start Date field. When the Start Date field is changed for a row, I need to set the value of another field in the same row to null.

I am having trouble detecting when a field is edited

I have read the [Kendo UI documentation on datasource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-change), specifically the change event section. It's clear the a change event of type "itemchange" is what I need. What I find strange is that when I change the Start Date field the only event that fires is a sync action. It may be worth noting that I have have autoSync : true set in my Datasource.

For context, here is a snip of what some of the grid looks like and the data source code. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image]

```
var componentsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    autoSync: true,
    transport: {
        read: function (e) {
            if ($scope.Booking.Components.length != 0) {
                e.success($scope.Booking.Components);
            }
            else {
                e.success([]);
            }
        },
        update: function (e) {
            e.success(e.data);
        },
        destroy: function (e) {
            $scope.loadNotesForBooking();
            e.success(e.data);
        }
    },
    change: function (e) {
        if (e.action === "itemchange") {
            console.log("A itemchange happened");
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $log.error("ComponentsDataSource error:");
        $log.error(e);
        messageService.setError(e.xhr, "componentsDataSource.transport.error", e);
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                ProductCode: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                Name: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                Status: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                Description: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                UnitDescription: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                StartDate: { type: "date", editable: true, nullable: false },
                NumberOfAdults: { type: "number", editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { min: 0, required: true } },
                NumberOfChildren: { type: "number", editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { min: 0, required: true } },
                NumberOfInfants: { type: "number", editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { min: 0, required: true } },
                Price: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                PickupLocation: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                DropoffLocation: { editable: true, nullable: true }
            }
        },
        parse: function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    if (item != null) {
                        //parse the data and convert the StartDate field (which comes through as a string) to a date so it can be formatted nicely by the grid
                        if (item.StartDate && typeof item.StartDate === "string") {
                            item.StartDate = kendo.parseDate(item.StartDate);
                        }
                        //build the description of the bus stops.  This is done by the busStopData source for the dropdown lists but needs to be built here for any bookings being loaded

                        if (item.PickupLocation) {
                            if (item.PickupLocation.Code != "") {
                                item.PickupLocation.Description = item.PickupLocation.Name + " - " + item.PickupLocation.Time;
                            }
                            else {
                                item.PickupLocation.Description = "";
                            }
                        }

                        if (item.DropoffLocation) {
                            if (item.DropoffLocation.Code != "") {
                                item.DropoffLocation.Description = item.DropoffLocation.Name + " - " + item.DropoffLocation.Time;
                            }
                            else {
                                item.DropoffLocation.Description = "";
                            }
                        }

                        //add GUID style Ids to notes.  This faciliates editing/deleting them from the grid as each can be uniquely identified
                        if (item.Remarks) {
                            if (item.Remarks.length > 0) {
                                $.each(item.Remarks, function (i, remark) {
                                    if (!remark.Id) {
                                        remark.Id = guid();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly how are you editing the data? I think that is the key thing here. Are you using the built in functions of the grid or doing something bespoke?

Comment: Just using a kendo datepicker

Comment: The kendo datepicker has an on change event that will work for what i need. thanks for making me think to look there NigelK